# reflexive pronoun use

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Which is better?  "You" vs. "Yourself" (referring to God)

"Draw us close to You." or "Draw us close to Yourself."

"Bring us back to You." or "Bring us back to Yourself."

Answer (score 1):

The better form is "Bring us back to yourself." The reflexive pronoun should be used when it refers to the subject of the sentence and an imperative has the implied subject "you".